# How do I stop browser resize of firefox and chrome in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, resize, resizable

Any one know how to stop the resize of firefox and chrome browser

Comment: From what? User interaction? Javascript? Divine intervention?

Comment: Apart from that it's bad style to do such a thing. So don't.

Comment: As a user, if I want to resize my browser, I will.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, unless you spawn a new window with those properties from your page.

To do that see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). **Disclaimer: w3schools is a bad site for reference. See [W3fools](http://w3fools.com/)**

Comment: If w3schools is bad, why do you reference it at all? MDC reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Comment: Thanks Felix, I didn't have time to do a better google search, so I just picked the top result. Your link is much better.

Comment: I think he was giving the answer to what the user wants, acknowledging it isn't advised to do and then warning him about the site. Anyone who wanted to give good advice wouldn't do this, so w3s is best option for a bad solution!